# Whats the diffrence between Java application and none java application?

Tags: android

How can we find out that an application is written in java or written in other languages.

Is there a difference between the application which is written in java and none java application?
I mean differences in look like. For example I saw some apps produced with phonegap that are so slow but so beautifull in design and animations. I haven't seen this effects in java.
Does it mean that java language is not able give us this ability to produce such apps with smooth animations and effects.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **reverse engineering**.

Comment: @DerGolem I've edited my question. please take a look and reconsider your opinion if its ok right now.

Comment: Yes it is much better, now. As @Suvitruf pointed out, the UI design doesn't depend on the language used. Performances do.

Comment: @DerGolem so could u please reopen the question.

Comment: No, I can't. It takes more than one user to reopen a question. And I wouldn't. The question still doesn't appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android application package (APK) is the package file format used **ONLY** to distribute and install application software and middleware onto **Google's Android** operating system.

I really don't understand what you mean when say "apk is written in java or written in other languages". It's just archive.

You can write program on Java/C++/Scala. But anyway .apk will looks same for all this languages.

Comment: :For example when you look at into an apk of a game which is made by unity3D, you can find out some specific library files and you will know this apk is made  by unity3D. My question is that is there another way to know that?

Comment: Why are you so much concerned about that?

Comment: @DerGolem There are some animation effects in some apps. I searched so much in java but nothing found. I want to know that with what language I can have those animations.

Comment: So the concept behind your question is completely wrong. It should be about animations, not about reverse engineering existing apps.

Comment: That's not about reverse engineering. That's just about comparing programming languages.
I think you are down voting me without no reason. that's not fair.